# Returning the location from the adapter back to the mainactivity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView and am trying to pass the location from my adapter back to the mainactivity without success so far .

I think the code in the adapter is passing the data back is working, but unfortunately I can’t work out how to set the initialisation in the onCreate in the MainActivity to work? I’m not certain how to call this using “*lazy*” (ie “private val itemAdapter by lazy” in the mainactivity”)?

I am getting frustrated solving this so any help appreciated.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
private val itemAdapter by lazy {
    ItemAdapter { position: Int, item: Item ->
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Pos ${position}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        item_list.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
    } }
private val possibleItems = listOf(
    Item("Plane 1", R.drawable.ic_airplane),
    Item("Car 2", R.drawable.ic_car),
    Item("Meals 3", R.drawable.ic_food),
    Item("Fuel 4", R.drawable.ic_gas),
    Item("Home 5 ", R.drawable.ic_home)
)
fun onImageClick(imageData: String?) {
    // handle image data
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    var position: Int
    val thisitem: Item
    var thisunit: Unit
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //       var itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(possibleItems)
    //       var thisitemAdapter = ItemAdapter((position, thisitem) -> thisunit)
    //          Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Pos ${position}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    //          item_list.smoothScrollToPosition(position) //CAN'T GET THIS TO COMPILE 
    item_list.initialize(itemAdapter)
    itemAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this) // Added this
    ItemSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(item_list)
    item_list.setViewsToChangeColor(listOf(R.id.list_item_background, R.id.list_item_text))
    item_list.scrollToPosition(Int.MAX_VALUE/2)
    itemAdapter.setItems(possibleItems)
}
override
public fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int ){
    Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast message" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
private fun getLargeListOfItems(): List<Item> {
    val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
    (0..40).map { items.add(possibleItems.random()) }
    return items
}
}
data class Item(
    val title: String,
    @DrawableRes val icon: Int
)
```

**ItemAdapter.kt**

```
class ItemAdapter(val itemClick: (position:Int,item:Item) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder>() {
private var items: List<Item> = listOf()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder =
    ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val pos = position % items.size
    holder.bind(items[pos])        // bind the actual item
    Log.d("xx position= ", pos.toString())
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int = Int.MAX_VALUE
fun setItems(newItems: List<Item>) {
    items = newItems
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int )
}
public fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.listener= listener
}
}
class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(item: Item) {
        view.list_item_text.text = "${item.title}"
        view.list_item_icon.setImageResource(item.icon)
     }
 }
```

Comment: `override fun getItemCount(): Int = Int.MAX_VALUE` What is this?  Are you repeating your items in recycler view? Why so? To mock a infinite list?

Comment: You have both a callback `itemClick` and an interface `OnItemClickListener` in your adapter. Why do you need both? And you are not calling any of these functions anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

you have a listener so you can write like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private lateinit var itemAdapter: ItemAdapter

private val possibleItems = listOf(
    Item("Plane 1", R.drawable.ic_airplane),
    Item("Car 2", R.drawable.ic_car),
    Item("Meals 3", R.drawable.ic_food),
    Item("Fuel 4", R.drawable.ic_gas),
    Item("Home 5 ", R.drawable.ic_home)
)
fun onImageClick(imageData: String?) {
    // handle image data
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    var position: Int
    val thisitem: Item
    var thisunit: Unit
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    itemAdapter = ItemAdapter()
    itemAdapter.listener = this
    item_list.initialize(itemAdapter)


    ItemSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(item_list)
    item_list.setViewsToChangeColor(listOf(R.id.list_item_background, R.id.list_item_text))
    item_list.scrollToPosition(Int.MAX_VALUE/2)
    itemAdapter.setItems(possibleItems)
}
override
public fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int ){
    Toast.makeText(this,"this is toast message" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
private fun getLargeListOfItems(): List<Item> {
    val items = mutableListOf<Item>()
    (0..40).map { items.add(possibleItems.random()) }
    return items
}
}
```

ItemAdapter.kt

```
 class ItemAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder>() {
    private var items: List<ClipData.Item> = listOf()
    var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder = ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position], position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = Int.MAX_VALUE
    fun setItems(newItems: List<ClipData.Item>) {
        items = newItems
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class ItemViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(item: ClipData.Item, position: Int) {

        view.list_item_text.text = "${item.title}"
        view.list_item_icon.setImageResource(item.icon)

        view.list_item_text.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.getAdapterPosition(position)
        }
    }
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun getAdapterPosition(position: Int)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I am struggling with “unresolved references”, namely in the MainActivity: `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ItemAdapter.**OnItemClickListener**`; and in the adapter: the bind: " `view.list_item_text.text = "${item.**title**}”`, in:"`view.list_item_icon.setImageResource(item. **icon**)`”, & in “**listener?.**getAdapterPosition(position)`” aren’t resolved? Really appreciate it, I've highlight **THIS** where it is not reosp;ved. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an interface you can also pass a lambda function as a callback to the Adapter.

Basic structure will be like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val itemAdapter = ItemAdapter { position ->
            // do whatever you wish with this position
        }
        recyclerView.adapter = itemAdapter
        ...
    }
}

class ItemAdapter(private val onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {

    ...

    inner class ItemViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(item: ClipData.Item, position: Int) {
            ...
            view.setOnClickListener {
                onClick(position)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you don't want to create `ItemViewHolder` as an inner class, you can accept the `onClick` lambda in its constructor and pass it there from `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: Please ask a new question adding your code and the errors you are getting. It will be easier to help you there.